# How do I login to the publishing console ?

Tags: appexchange

Salesforce has recently changed their Appexchange UI. How do I login to my publishing console?

Answer (score 2):

There has been a partner alert issued for this here:

https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerAlert?id=a033000000C8v3CAAR

The relevant text of this is:

> **Who is impacted by this?** Any partner user who previously used the
>   AppExchange Publishing Console to maintain their managed packages or
>   AppExchange listings, but will now need access (via the ‘Manage
>   Listings’ permission) to the new Publishing Console in the Partner
>   Community.
>
> **What is the change?** The AppExchange Publishing Experience is moving to the Partner Community! Beginning Friday, July 24th, you will
>   be able to create and manage your AppExchange listing in the Partner
>   Community.
>
> **What action do I need to take?** A new “Manage Listings” permission is now available through the Manage Users page of the Partner
>   Community. This permission was previously available as “Manage Apps”
>   and may already be assigned to some users.

Comment: Can you please answer the question - where doI log in? That link is just to the notice.